# Can loose souls hide in males?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

After finishing the first season, I have noticed that all the loose souls so far have been hiding in female hosts.  I realize it makes sense for the male protagonist to be working with females, but is it *possible* for a male to have a loose soul?  Perhaps there is a female counterpart to Keima that deals with the males?

Comment: spirits would hide only in girls, but the one who capture it doesn't have to be male. Haqua's buddy is a 54 y/o saleswoman

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a reason why the runaway spirits hide in females. A runaway spirit can be reborn as the child of a female host. For this reason, essentially all runaway spirits have female hosts. As far as I know it has never been explicitly addressed whether a runaway spirit is capable of possessing a male host, but even if they could it wouldn't be of any benefit to them since the primary goal of the spirits is to be reincarnated.

This was explained in chapter 3 of the manga (before the Mio conquest), but at least according to @ShinobuOshino below in the comments, not in the anime. It does come up in some future arcs though (I'll avoid spoiling exactly when), so it may be mentioned later in the anime.

[image]

Comment: Seems odd to try to get girls pregnant but if they fall in love then the loose souls are ejected from the host.  I think this was mentioned somewhere in Season 2 though never really a good explanation in the anime.

Comment: @LoganM it's in chapter 3 from manga when they are about to meet Aoyama Mio, it didn't happen in anime though

Comment: @ShinobuOshino Thanks. I meant to look for it myself but didn't get much chance. For some reason I thought it was later than that.

Comment: @DavidStarkey I should probably clarify something. Runaway spirits are reborn from their hosts. However, the mechanics of this aren't 100% clear. The host does need to be able to get pregnant (so elderly women and young girls are not viable) but as far as I know it's never been explained exactly how they would be impregnated. It's possible that the spirits themselves are capable of impregnating their hosts.